# como hago para que mis mensajes se muestren de abajo hacia arriba

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

estoy creando un chat pero el único problema que me hace falta es poner el efecto que caracteriza un chat y es que los mensajes vayan de abajo hacia arriba.

lo tengo así:

- recien publicado
- no.2
- no.3

--enviar mensaje--

pero quiero que sea así:

- no.2
- no.1
- recien publicado

--enviar mensaje--

¿hay que modificar el css? ¿como lo logro?

Comment: Hola @code2018, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este ejemplo he hecho que en el div chat se cree un nuevo p cada vez que se escriba un mensaje, y de esa forma cada nuevo p se coloca debajo del anterior, tienes mucho que mejorar en este código pero espero que te sirva para conseguir lo que quieres.

```js
var chat = document.getElementById("chat");
function enviar() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  chat.appendChild(p);
  p.innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

```css
.chat {width:150px;height:150px;border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div class="chat" id="chat">
</div>
<input type="text" id="input">
<input type="button" id="boton" value="Enviar" onclick="enviar()">
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacer que cuando tengas el nuevo mensaje lo agregues al contenedor y le anexas lo que ya tenias.

Por ejemplo:  JS

```
var text = document.getElementById("contenedor");
text.innerHTML = nuevoMensage + text.textContent;
```

si pones así

```
text.innerHTML =  text.textContent + nuevoMensage;
```

se anexara al final.

Saludos